# angular Material Tabs do not change their content

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm starting to learn AngularJS and Angular Material.

I have a problem on understanding the md-tabs.

```
<section layout="row">
    <div layout="column"><img id="ApplicationLogo" src="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/img/icons/angular-logo.svg"></div>
    <div layout="column" id="ApplicationTitle" layout-align="center start">Application Title</div>
    <div layout="column" id="ApplicationWelcome" flex layout-align="center end">Angemeldet als Test User</div>
    <div layout="column" layout-align="center center"><img id="ApplicationAvatar" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/d05.png"></div>
</section>
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/72ZNb70BjSM6xP7RnSvH?p=preview

Any hint why my tabs do not change their content?

Answer (score 0):

you linked to wrong angular material css version.

you used angular-material.js 1.0.7 and angular-material.css 1.1.0-rc2.

changed to the correct version of css should work. (/1.0.7/angular-material.css)

The reason that it didn't work was that the required css class md-visually-hidden in 1.0.7 is renamed to _md-visually-hidden in the 1.1.0.

Don't want to go into too much detail unless you ask for. But try to correct the version and see what happen.

Comment: You are correct sir. I made a jsfiddle with correct sources and it works at https://jsfiddle.net/x9ayqog3/1 . If you want you can add this to your answer. (Sorry can't upvote you because my daily limit is full but this should be marked as the correct answer).